shared-preferences causing issue with building flutter application
I've created a flutter project (mobile app for ios & android).
I'm developing on a windows machine with VSCode & Android Studio for emulating a device.
My colleague has merged changes to main (they are developing on macOS).
They have introduced a new dependency shared-preferences used to store tokens after registration and login.
In pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.3.3

In auth_service.dart
if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('access', data['access']);
    await prefs.setString('refresh', data['refresh']);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to register: ${response.body}');
  }
} catch (e) {
  throw Exception('Connection failed: $e');
}

When I run the command flutter run (targeting the android emulator device)
I see
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':shared_preferences_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
   > Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 3s

When I run flutter run a choose a web application as my target, there are no build issues.
Versions

gradle: 8.10.2
flutter version: 3.24.4
android (emulator) api: I've tried 33, 34 & 35
Android Studio: Ladybug 2024.2.1

I've tried

flutter clean, flutter upgrade, flutter pub upgrade
setting a minsdk version in android/app/build.gradle
uninstall and re-install android studio

